# macOS Catalina: trying to install content to the system volume

Tags: macos-catalina, pkgbuild

I have apps that I distribute as `.pkg` files created using `pkgbuild` and `productbuild`.  With macOS Catalina, this doesn't work any more.  The installer complains that I'm trying to install content to the system volume.

I posted three weeks ago thinking the error had to do with bundling a Java runtime.  It turns out it has nothing to do with Java.

To test it I have the smallest possible project called Hello with a main window and a button to click.  In XCode, I do Product -> Archive, then Distribute App, and Copy App.  This creates a directory `Hello 2019-12-18 15-01-07` with contents `Hello.app`.  The app works fine.  I then
    `pkgbuild --root *7 Hello.pkg`
which creates `Hello.pkg`.

When I double-click Hello.pkg in the finder the installer presents me with screens for Introduction, Destination Select (only one option is offered), and Installation type ("Standard Install on Macintosh HD"), then asks me for my password.  It then says, "This package is incompatible with this version of macOS.  The package is trying to install content to the system volume.  Contact the software manufacturer for assistance."

It makes no difference if I codesign and notarize.  Productbuild only adds one more layer to the failing process.

What am I missing?

Comment: The system partition is now read-only, unless you disable SIP.  You might take a look at creating a synthetic symbolic link - see `man synthetic.conf`.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I could set something up to install the app on my own computer, but the objective is to create an installer than any user can click on.  Before Catalina that was accomplished with pkgbuild and productbuild.  Is there another set of tools I should use instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We could fix the issue by using the option

```
--install-location
```

of the `pkgbuild` command.

If the

```
--install-location
```

option is not used, `pkgbuild` uses `/` as the default install location in many cases.

In macOS Catalina, only certain folders are writable. Refer this [link](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/10/08/macos-catalina-boot-volume-layout/) for more details.

In our case, the package installation succeeded only when we specified one of the writable folders such as

```
/usr/local
/opt
/Applications
```

as the default install location.

Comment: Could able to install the package in root and Applications folder. Is there any way to install our package in system volume(Documents folder) without disable SIP?